# I have plan data and want parent children combination. Angular

Tags: angular

I have following data:

```
1.[0 … 40]
1.  0:
      1.    id: "1"
      2.    type: "ABC"
      3.    description: " ABC "                       
2.  1: 
      1.    id: "2"
      2.    type: "ABC"
      3.    description: " ABC "
      4.    parentId: "1"
3.  2:
      1.    id: "3"
      2.    type: "ABC"
      3.    description: " ABC "                       
4.  3: 
      1.    id: "4"
      2.    type: "ABC"
      3.    description: " ABC "
5.  4: 
      1.    id: "5"
      2.    type: "ABC"
      3.    description: " ABC "
      4.    parentId: "4"
```

I want following output:

```
1.  0:
    1.  children: 
        1.  id: "2"
        2.  type: "BDC"
        3.  description: " BCD "
        4.  parentId: "1"
2.  data:
        1.  id: "1"
        2.  type: "ABC"
        3.  description: " ABC "                       
2.  1: {data: {…}, children: Array(2)}
3.  2: {data: {…}, children: Array(2)}
4.  3: {data: {…}, children: Array(2)}
```

Using Angular 8, and I want these format as I need to display in PrimeNg Tree Table

Comment: Where is your code showing what you have done so far to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interface GroupedData {
  data: any;
  children: GroupedData[];
}

function groupData(originalArray: any[]): GroupedData[] {
  // Convert all elements for GroupedData shape in an object
  // having the id's as the keys
  const tempObj: { [id: string]: GroupedData } = array.reduce(
      (acc, item) =>
        (acc = { ...acc, [item.id]: { data: item, children: [] } }),
      {}
    );

  // put each child in the right parent's children array
  originalArray.forEach((item: any) => {
    if (item.parentId) {
      tempObj[item.parentId].children.push(tempObj[item.id]);
    }
  });

  // filter out all the GroupedData that has a valid data.parentId
  // and convert the final result to an array
  return Object.keys(tempObj)
      .map((key: string) => (tempObj[key].data.parentId ? null : tempObj[key]))
      .filter(Boolean);
}
```

If you want to work with a more formal typed structure, backed in the core of the language, you can declare `tempObj` as a typescript `Map<string, GroupedData>`:

```js
function groupData(originalArray: any[]): GroupedData[] {
  // Convert all elements for GroupedData shape in a Map
  // having the id's as the keys
  const tempMap: Map<string, GroupedData> = new Map(
    originalArray.map(item => [item.id, { data: item, children: [] }])
  );

  // put each child in the right parent's children array
  originalArray.forEach((item: any) => {
    if (item.parentId) {
      tempMap.get(item.parentId).children.push(tempMap.get(item.id));
    }
  });

  // filter out all the GroupedData that has a valid data.parentId
  // and convert the final result to an array.
  // In ES6, you have some Array static methods, like Array.from()
  return Array.from(tempMap)
    .map(([key,value]) => (value.data.parentId ? null : value))
    .filter(Boolean);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. its almost solve my problem. I need one more help from you.i want to add data inside children like this                                                                                                              
    1.  0:
       children: Array2
       0.  data: { id: "2", type: "BCD", description: "BCD", parentId: "1"}
       1. data: { id: "6", type: "XYZ", description: "XYZ", parentId: "1"}

Comment: Here 'data' is not parent it is just a element inside children

Comment: You mean that all objects must have the same shape, even the children. That's simple. I'll update my answer.

Comment: While I was on that, I took the opportunity to improve the code a little bit. Now you can map the array to what you want, no matter the relationship between parents/child is. The previous code supposed that you had the parents and only one level of children. This code allows for any level of children, so you can have grandchildren, great grandchildren etc. No limits.